# Why is my table before the section title?

Tags: tables, floats

I would like to change the position of my table so that it is not `before` the title of the current section as show in my screenshot [image]
.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
\subsection{Cinétique d'oxydation des joints de grains avec teneur nominale en chrome}

La cinétique blah blah blah
d'essai.

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Données utilisées pour la calibration de la cinétique d'oxydation des joints de grains présentant une teneur nominale en chrome à 320/325°C}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\textbf{Repère} & \textbf{Échantillon} & \textbf{pox max (nm)} &     \textbf{Température (°C)} & \textbf{Temps (h)} \\
    \hline
    \hline
B356 (TT 1h x 720°C) & 1816-22 & 10 & 325 & 0,16 \\
    \hline
T265 & 1866-20 & 307 & 325 & 100 \\
    \hline
B356 SA & 1866-187 & 847 & 320 & 1000 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular} 
}
\label{tab:calibrecinetique}
\end{table}}
\FloatBarrier

Sur la Figure
```

I have no idea why LaTeX always prints the table `before` the title, as I have enough place `after` (this is the beginning of the page). I've tried to use as for image the `[H]` to force the positionning, and also the `FloatBarrier` to force the cache of floating objects to be released (it would work if the table is printed ways after, which is not the case here).

Comment: you need `\begin{table}[htp]` in order to allow the figure to appear mid-page (`h`) also you might want to add `\usepackage{flafter}` which prevents figures ever floating backwards up the current page.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you so much! tex.se provides me with so many solutions, I can't see right know way to give back. I you make your comment a solution, I will mark my question as resolved.

Comment: The question is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285238/avoid-figure-above-section-title/285242#285242 but the answer there only mentions flafter not also using h . maybe I will answer here as well .

Comment: If you use \clearpage before the section heading, it solves the problem too.

Comment: Aside: do not `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}` a tabular.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> I know that it is not a popular solution on this site but I like it
> anyway.

- The `float` package offers an additional placement parameter/option called `H`. If you use it then the float object (figure or table) is exactly placed where you put it in the code.
- Normally you want floating objects to float and let LaTeX decide where to put it.
- But with the following approach that I describe here, you have full manual control of the float position if you want to.
- You can still combine this approach with the other solutions mentioned here (`flafter` package and `!htb` placement parameter). Just decide from table to table (or figure and figure) what is best.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float} % here for H placement parameter

\begin{document}

Text before table.    

\begin{table}[H] % placement parameter H
    \centering % if you want to center the table
    \caption{Table showing \ldots}
    \label{table:ExampleTable}
    % Code for table
\end{table}

Text after table.      

\end{document}
```

> By the way, normally you want to have a little unbreakable space
> between the number and the unit: `720\,°C` or `720~°C`. Where `\,` is a half space and `~` a full space. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41476/lengths-and-when-to-use-them) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76132/how-to-typeset-a-small-non-breaking-space) for further information. But this is not
> related to the question at all.

Comment: I came across a situation where even using `[H]` Latex put a table before the section title. To fix this I inserted \quad\\ immediately after the section title.

Answer (score 12):

You need `\begin{table}[htp]` in order to allow the figure to appear mid-page (`h`).

Also you might want to add

```
\usepackage{flafter}
```

which prevents figures ever floating backwards up the current page

So with `flafter` (but not `h`) the float will appear at the bottom of the current page or top of the next.

With `[htpb]` then without `flafter` the order that is tried is `h`, `t` on this page, `b` on this page, `p`, `t` on next page. (But it is `t` on this page that you want to avoid).

With `[htpb]` then with`flafter` the order that is tried is `h`,  `b` on this page, `p`, `t` on next page.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `[!htbp]` option. I also used `makecell` and `siunitx` to have a nicer formatting of the table, so you don't have to use `\resizebox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, french]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, caption}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight, range-phrase=/, range-units = single}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{section}{3}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Cinétique d'oxydation des joints de grains avec teneur nominale en chrome}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[!hbt]
  \centering\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \caption{Données utilisées pour la calibration de la cinétique d'oxydation des joints de grains présentant une teneur nominale en chrome à \SIrange{320}{325}{\celsius}}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \thead{Repère} & \thead{Échantillon} & \thead{pox max & & \\ (nm)} & \thead {Température \\ (\si{\celsius})} & \thead{Temps\\ (h)} \\
    \hline
    \hline
    B356 (TT 1\,h $ \times $ \SI{720}{\celsius}) & 1816-22 & 10 & 325 & 0,16 \\
    \hline
    T265 & 1866-20 & 307 & 325 & 100 \\
    \hline
    B356 SA & 1866-187 & 847 & 320 & 1000 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:calibrecinetique}
\end{table}

\lipsum[3]

\subsection{Cinétique d'oxydation des carbures de chrome}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @David Carlisle: Right. I changed to [!hbt] (top being last preferred).

Comment: I agree floats should, well… float in general. However in some special circumstances, they shouldn't float too far away.

Comment: Yes, I've learnt that today! For some reason, I thought the order of the letters was significant. Answer corrected.