# Section starts after the timeline, yet it is supposed to start before it

Tags: errors

So I tried to make a timeline and finally found a template that I could use, but the 'Timeline'(ligne du temps) section, which is supposed to be on top of the page, starts after the timeline. I'm not used to LaTeX yet, so I mostly use the same base document all the time, which results in the large numbers of packages that are mostly useless for a timeline, but I do not know which ones I can delete without creating other issues with my document

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,includehead=true,headheight=1cm]{geometry}%Pour ajustement des marges.
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}
\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}

\pagestyle{fancy}%Numéros de page en haut de la page
\fancyhf{} %Numéros de page en haut de la page
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} %R pour numéros de page à droite et L à gauche


\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\renewcommand\frenchtablename{\textsc{Tableau}}

\sisetup{locale = FR,separate-uncertainty=true,list-units=repeat,multi-part-units=brackets,per-mode=symbol}


\parskip=10pt 
\parindent=0pt
\onehalfspacing
\fboxsep=9pt

%Pour créer des vecteurs avec une lettre normale ou une lettre grecque
\newcommand{\vecteur}[1]{
\vv{\mathbf{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\vecteurg}[1]{
\vv{\boldsymbol{#1}}
}


\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}





\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{2cm}  

\textbf{Ligne du temps des événements majeurs de la Grande Guerre}
\vspace{0.5cm}
305-KUL 
\vspace{1.5cm}
\textbf{Name}

\vfill
Un \\Name
\vspace{0.8cm}

Département \\Cégep \\
\today
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\newpage



\section{Ligne du temps}


\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
\toprule
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
1979 & Référendum sur la dévolution de l'Écosse \newline (Oui: 51,6\%, Non: 48,4\%)\\
1997 & Référendum sur la dévolution de l'Écosse \newline (Oui: 74.3\%, Non: 25.7\%)\\
1998 & \textit{Scotland Act}\\
1999 & Création du parlement écossais à Holyrood\\
2007 & Élection du \textit{Scottish National Party} minoritaire\\
2011 & Élection du \textit{Scottish National Party} majoritaire\\
2012 & Accord d'Édimbourg\\
2013 & \textit{Scottish Referendum Act}\\
2014 & Référendum sur la sécession de l'Écosse \newline (Oui: 44,6\%, Non: 55,4\%)\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seeing this mess of a code, I have so many questions. Also, as it is now, it doesn't actually compile. Consider e.g. the % signs in your table. You'd have to at least escape them using `\%`. But your question is most likely related to the fact, that the `table` environment is a float, that means it will be typeset to a position LaTeX finds the most suitable. Typically that will be the top of the page and even above section titles, unless there is text between the `\section{}` and the `\begin{table}`. Otherwise, try `\begin{table}[ht]`.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297564/why-is-my-table-before-the-section-title